# C# Textlabel Fade in/out

Tags: c#, winforms, textlabel

I am looking to have a textlabel fade in and out on a button press. I notice that textlabel does not have an opacity parameter. Is there another way that I can achieve the desired result ?

Comment: [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.aspx) you mean?

Comment: In short, it's quite complex, but here is a link that provides a fully functional example (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/ded003e3-ab35-4c23-b645-af7f82df57f0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinForms do not support this.

You could use a [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) control with text on it and use a fade effect by swapping colors in a timer event.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that it's not supported (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/ded003e3-ab35-4c23-b645-af7f82df57f0).

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for `Control` Opacity in `Winform`.

In .Net Framework only `Form` is capable of showing opacity property, `Controls` on the Form have same `Opacity` to that of `parent Form`.

Answer (score 0):

To fade a monochrome text label in/out, I have successfully used a timer to read the ForeColor of the label, scale the R component as required, then set a new ForeColour. E.g. to fade out:

```
    private void LabelFader_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var colour = myLabel.ForeColor;
        byte cR = colour.R;

        if (cR < 210) // Set whatever limit you want, 0-255
            cR++; // cR-- to fade in
        else
            labelFader.Stop();
        myLabel.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, cR, cR, cR);
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

I guess, you are looking for something like that:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (label1.Visible) label1.Visible = false;
    else label1.Visible = true;
}
```